# Performant strategies to handle rate limits

Tags: spring-boot, java-11, rate-limiting

I have a Spring Boot app (Java 11) that consumes messages from a RabbitMQ queue and calls a third party rest-api (besides other things). The third party rest-api enforces well known rate limits. Are there established strategies (libraries, algorithms etc...) to limit calls within the permitted rate that would

1. Avoid blocking threads
2. Be durable (i.e. survive application restarts)
3. Be scalable (i.e. multiple instances of the application confirming to the rate limit)

Comment: Have you looked at https://github.com/bucket4j/bucket4j ? It seems they claim to have what you ask for.

Comment: I haven't looked at it. Thank you for the suggestion.